# Referencing values of an array of pointers to arrays

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to create an array containing 8 other arrays.  I've a function that puts these arrays in a larger array.  I'm having trouble referencing my data in the subarrays:

```
void randomGen(int arr[]){
// fill vec10-vec1000000 with random values
arr[0] = *vec10;
arr[1] = *vec100;
arr[2] = *vec1000;
arr[3] = *vec10000;
arr[4] = *vec100000;
arr[5] = *vec100000;
arr[6] = *up;
arr[7] = *down;
}
```

I'm testing this in main, and I can't find a way to access anything but the first value in each array.  I'm not sure what the first column is showing, the second column is the first entry in each of vec10-vec1000000, and the third is simply iterating +1 on the first entry. How do I format this so that I can access my sub-arrays? Is my function doomed?

```
First 4 elements of vec10: 12 5 9 17 
0: *(*(&a+i)): 12; *(a+i): 12; *(a)+i: 12
1: *(*(&a+i)): 0; *(a+i): 1144108930; *(a)+i: 13
2: *(*(&a+i)): 0; *(a+i): 984943658; *(a)+i: 14
3: *(*(&a+i)): 0; *(a+i): 1622650073; *(a)+i: 15
4: *(*(&a+i)): 0; *(a+i): 282475249; *(a)+i: 16
5: *(*(&a+i)): 0; *(a+i): 282475249; *(a)+i: 17
6: *(*(&a+i)): 0; *(a+i): 0; *(a)+i: 18
7: *(*(&a+i)): 0; *(a+i): 9999; *(a)+i: 19
8: *(*(&a+i)): 0; *(a+i): 0; *(a)+i: 20
9: *(*(&a+i)): 0; *(a+i): 0; *(a)+i: 21
```

Comment: **vec10-vec100000, up** and **down** are int arrays right? Where are they coming from? If that's the case your **arr** parameter should be a 2d array in your function signature: `void randomGen(int** arr)` and then you can access its values using arr[i][j], where **i** and **j** represent your row and your column being accessed.

Comment: Yes, these vectors are int arrays. I tried your suggestion @Santiago-Varela, I'm getting a exc bad access error.  I made the following adjustments: `int **a;' declared in main, `void randomGen(int **arr){`, and `arr[0] = vec10;` in the randomGen function, and `for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        cout << i << ": a[i][j]: " << a[i][0]; << " "<< a[i][0];` in a for loop to test values. I'm a bit lost.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Following code snippets can help go over those things concerning pointers and arrays.

```
// say you have
int a[10], b[10], c[10];
// you can 
int *p[3] = {a, b, c}; // implicit conversion from int[10] to int *
// or
int (*pa[3])[10] = {&a, &b, &c};
// which is equivalent to
using Array10 = int[10];
using PointerToArray10 = Array10 *;
PointerToArray10 another_pa[3] = {&a, &b, &c};
```

---

```
// say you have
int d[10], e[11], f[12];
// you can still
int *pp[3] = {d, e, f};
```

---

```
// say you have
void randomGen(int arr[])
// there isn't anything you can do
```

---

**What you need is**

```
void randomGen(int *arr[]) {
  arr[0] = a; // no deference, the same a as declared before
  arr[1] = f;
}
```

Since those arrays which you want to "store" in the `arr` have different type(bound), the only option is to store the address of each array's first element, i.e. &a[0]. `Arr` thus need to have the type `an array of pointers` (each element of this array is a pointer).

But one can't declare array as function parameter, they will always decay to pointer. So here is the deal, you declare an array of pointer somewhere:

```
int *array[10];
```

and then pass it to the function

```
randomGen(array);
```

and the function use the array you passed to initialise a pointer to pointer, i.e. `int **arr` or `int *arr[]` (they are the same in parameter list), with array-to-pointer conversion. And the function parameter in fact will point to the first element of the `array`, i.e. `&array[0]`. (`array[0]` has type `int *`, `&array[0]` has type `int **`)

Inside the function you can access the element of the original array through the pointer.

```
arr[0] // array[0]
```